# Array to checkbox with some checked depending on MtM

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables: paginas, slider, pages_header(containing an id of the page + the slider)

I need to get **all** the pages from the pages table and then check in the paginas_slider table if they have a specified slider connected to it. Im trying to do this in pure mysql, but I'm not sure if this is even possible.

What I'm trying to use is this:

```
SELECT *
FROM paginas 
LEFT JOIN pagina_slider ON paginas.id = pagina_slider.pagina
WHERE pagina_slider.slider = '1'
```

The problem is that this only gives the pages that have the slider with id '1' connected to it (makes perfect sense).
The thing i want is that it spits out all pages from the paginas table and that it does an extra check to see if it has a slider connected to it.

Could anyone help me out on this?

Comment: How's anyone supposed to help you without a single bit of code?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to limit your results but would still like to add a conditional, you can use an `IF` to give you the necessary data.

In this case, `hasSlider` will be 1 if it has the slider attached to it or 0 otherwise:

```
SELECT *, IF(pagina_slider.slider = '1', 1, 0) AS hasSlider
FROM paginas 
LEFT JOIN pagina_slider ON paginas.id = pagina_slider.pagina
```

Comment: After checking this solution if found out that its not working 100%. For instance: When there is multiple instances of the same page in the DB you will get duplicates of the page. I could group these to hide this, but this will also mean that the result is not waterproof.

Comment: @Nick If that is the case, then it isn't easy to infer a solution. You should post your schema.

Comment: I have 3 tables: **pages** -> id, title, content. **sliders** id, title, content, **slider_pages** -> id, page_id, slider_id. I want to be able to generate checkboxes from the pages table (with a certain page selected) and check if there is a slider connected to that page. The thing is that i want to select _all_ the pages (even the one without a slider) and create a checkbox for those.